# Failed to send Post Request in MERN

Tags: html, reactjs, mern

In my MERN app I'm facing problem while saving send post request to server For saving Data I used is  mongo dB Atlas. Everything working fine in my localhost but after deploying that same app I facing this issue. I don't the reason behind this but please check my **form tag in contact.js** first may be help u to find bug. Please help me out to fix this.

My Contact.js file (client side)

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import axios from 'axios';
class Contact extends React.Component
 {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={
   name:'',email:'',feedback:''
  }
}

del=(event)=>
 {
   var objname=event.target.name;
   var objvalue=event.target.value;
       if(objname==="name")
           this.setState({name:objvalue});
       else if(objname==="email")
           this.setState({email:objvalue});
       else if(objname==="feedback")
           this.setState({feedback:objvalue});

  }


 alertBox=()=>{
      alert('Successfully Submitted');
     }


 detail=()=>{

  console.log("well come back dear!!");
  axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/details",this.state);
   this.alertBox();
   }

 render()
    {
     return(
   <>
     <Header />

     <div className="my-3 pt-4 mx-auto" style={{backgroundColor:'coral'}}>
      <div className="container-fluid" style={{position:'relative', top:'20%',background:'transparent'}}>
              <div className="container pt-5 shadow-lg text-dark" >
                <div className="row"> 
                    <div className="col-sm-6 ">
                        <div><h1><u>My Contacts</u></h1></div>
                        <div>
                        <ul type="none">
                            <li><span>NAME :</span> <h2><i className="far fa-user"> </i> YASHAV KUMAR</h2></li>
                            <li><span>Email :</span> <h2><i className="fas fa-phone"></i> yashavkumar91@gmail.com</h2></li>
                            <li><span>ADDRESS :</span> <h2><i className="fas fa-address-card"></i> Kangra (H.P), India</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-6">
                        <div><h1><u>Please Send Your Feedback!!</u></h1></div>
                        <form action="/" method='GET' onSubmit={this.detail}>

                        <table className="table text-light">
                          <tbody>
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                  <h1><i className="far fa-user"></i></h1><label>Name </label>
                               </td>
                                <td>
                                 <input className="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg" name="name" type="text" required placeholder="Your Name" onChange={this.del.bind(this)}/>
                                </td>

                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                 <h1><i className="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></h1>
                                 <label>Email  </label>
                               </td>
                              <td>
                                <input className="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg" name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Your Email" onChange={this.del.bind(this)}/>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                               <h1><i className="fas fa-grin-squint"></i></h1>
                               <label>Your Suggestions </label>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                               <textarea className="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg" name="feedback" type="text"placeholder="Your text here" height="140px" required onChange={this.del.bind(this)}></textarea>
                              </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                               <td>
                                 <input className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-secondary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit"/>
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                 <input className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-secondary btn-lg" type="reset" name="Reset"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
   </>
)
 }

 }

export default Contact;
```

My App.js (server side)

```
 app.post("/details",(req,res)=>{

      res.json({msg:"Good work buddy"});
      const {name,email,feedback}=req.body;

  const object=new Reviews(
   {
 _id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
 Name:name,
 Email:email,
 Feedback:feedback,
  });
  object.save()
     .then(
        (response)=>{
             console.log(response);
          }
        )
     .catch((err)=>{
         console.log(err);
         res.status(500).json({msg:"Please recheck the data"})
        })

  res.end();
      })
```

---

For More Project Visit :- https://react-website-liart.vercel.app/  (client)
https://yashavreact.herokuapp.com/reviewdata (server)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZlXV.png)

Thanks for reviewing my code.

Comment: can you put some description of the issue you are facing on production server?

Comment: Sure  I'm adding some  issue images also

Comment: @Mohiuddinkhanromi sir actually project is  hosted on heroku so console is not working.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue could be with CORS origin not sure about it. Can't say without the issue description.

Comment: No problem buddy